# Why I get error "An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:" when run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have followed this guide [Using Models In Your Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations). Now I want to add a new column called `suspect` type boolean into Question table, it will have default value is `false`, and I want to update records have created too. This is my migration file:

```
class AddSuspectToQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def change
    add_column :questions, :suspect, :boolean, default: false
    Question.reset_column_information
    Question.all.each do |question|
      question.update_attributes!(suspect: false)
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run `rake db:migrate`, it has error:

```
==  AddSuspectToQuestions: migrating ==========================================
-- add_column(:questions, :suspect, :boolean, {:default=>false})
   -> 0.3782s
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: suspect
```

I think it needs `attr_accesible :suspect`, so I added it in Question model, but I still has same error when I run migrate again. I have set this in `application.rb` too:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Anyone has met this problem?

Comment: As Lichtamberg mentions, the `faux model` in your migration doesn't have `attr_accessible :suspect`, and that's why it is failing. On a different note, since you want `suspect` column to be `false` for all records (both new and old) you don't need to do second part of the migration(setting `suspect` to `false` for each of the Question records). `add_column :questions, :suspect, :boolean, default: false` will do it automatically for you.

Comment: It worked too :D, I just checked it. Thanks for explain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesnt work, since you are overwriting the Question Class in your migration.

Remove

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and try it again.

Comment: ok im not sure if it really works, maybe thats not the problem

Comment: It worked !, but I don't know why guide of rails add it to migration file. Thanks so much.

Comment: i also dont know why they added it.. :/